# Access Denied: shared folder between Win host and ubuntu guest using VM

Tags: permissions, mount, virtualbox

I created `shared` folder in Windows and linked it to Ubuntu through VM settings-Shared Folder-Added path-name.

Now this `shared` folder is not accessible when I start the ubuntu OS. I added my username to the `vboxsf` group and restarted guest OS, tried logging out-logging back in but the problem persists.

How to resolve the issue? I am getting access denied on ubuntu.

Comment: @N0rbert : No. I tried all of the options given in the link you provided. It's still saying access denied. And if I am manually mounting the guest folder, I can access the folder but it's not showing any bidirectional changes between host and guest shared folder.

Comment: removed my answer after seeing Norbert's comment... mine was somewhat similar to the first one on that page except that I am using /etc/fstab to auto-mount and I am explicitly declaring the options... FYI, my user is not a member of vboxsf. Who is the owner of the mount point-unmounted? Who is the owner of the directory and files when mounted?

Comment: Have you installed the guest additions?

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes, see this https://imgur.com/a/iVBFlr5

Comment: @WU-TANG root is the owner of the sf_sharedfolder. Hence it says permission denied. I tried to change permissions by using chown 777 and i was able to access the folder but the changes were not being reflected between windows folder and ubuntu folder

Comment: I am confused by what you are saying. it may just be semantics (or I just dont remember the sf_sharedfolder context)... but I asked about your mount point, and it TWO states, the folder that YOU specifically created to mount your share. "sf_sharedfolder" if I recall correctly sounds like the auto-name given to the share itself (correct me if i am wrong). if so, how would that be "root" if it is a Windows share? (again maybe semantics). You are probably going to have to edit some detail into your question. Show what you have configured. I am going to show my answer again with some more detail.

Comment: @WU-TANG I am getting confused too. Looks like we are talking about different setup. So I created a sharedfolder on windows. Then on Ubuntu VM settings, I added the path to this sharedfolder on "Shared Folder" settings and checked the auto-mount option. Now when I start the ubuntu OS, I see the same folder listed under /media as sf_sharedfolder. But access is denied. It's owner is root.

Comment: @WU-TANG check this https://imgur.com/a/MsRYy0G at present, I am seeing access denied and root is the owner of sf_sharebox (the shared folder between windows and ubuntu)

Comment: @learner57 I'm clear on it now. I forgot the particulars about the sf_mountpoint that's automatically created because I never use it. Shame on me for not testing it. I use a different method (my answer below). I did a quick test and made another share, but my ownership ends up root:vboxsf. And by adding my user to the vboxsf group I was able to r/w. Personally I don't care for this method, I just create my own directory and add the line in /etc/fstab, that you see in my answer below, so that it auto mounts without virtualbox's help. I found my own mount point was easier to manage. See my edit

Comment: @WU-TANG I hear you. I added my username to the vboxsf group and I am still unable to get an access to the shared folder.

Comment: @learner57 you dont have the same ownership of the directory as I do on my directory. that is what I was pointing out. Your mount point ownership is root:root.. root user, root group... My ownership is root:vboxsf. root user, vboxsf group. So I am able to add myself to the vboxsf group and work. I actually do see the same thing on my system with the automatically created mount points (sf_xxxyyzz)... so i don't bother to use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Situation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHFKy.jpg Can't access shared folder between Windows Host and Guest Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Troubleshooting : The problem was in VirtualBox Guest Additions.

Solution: I followed these steps:

1. Fresh VirtualBox Guest Additions installation.
2. When Ubuntu rebooted, I checked if my username was in the `vboxsf` group by checking entry in `cat /etc/group` (It was already present)
3. I created a new folder `vboxshare` on windows host.
4. On VirtualBox settings -> Shared Folder, I added the path to `vboxshare` on "Add Share" window and checked "Auto Mount"
5. I booted the Ubuntu guest machine. Now I was able to access the `sf_vboxshare` folder under `/media/` and the vboxshare folder on Windows Host and Ubuntu Guest are now in sync!

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKBed.jpg

Comment: good find... good to know that Guest Additions causes the problem (or that reinstalling Guest Additions triggered some other fix action)... Makes me wonder if you were running an old version of Guest Additions and now you've upgraded? I still prefer having my user actually own the folder and avoiding /media/sf_folders.

Answer (score 0):

I mount my shared folder in /etc/fstab like:

`sharedsfname  /files  vboxsf  rw,noexec,auto,nouser,uid=1000,gid=1000  0  0`

The **uid/gid=userid** option is the key in my case... Without it I have the same issue that you are experiencing.

I have a linux on linux setup though, so I am not sure about the effects with a Windows host.

In my example

- I am creating my shared folder and checking 'make permanent' (always clicking OK, to accept the changes)
- I am creating my own folder on my guest called **/files**.... owned and r/w by my user.
- Using the shared folder name **(NOT THE AUTO-NAME mount point, created by virtualbox?: sf_XXXXXXXX)**, This is the name that you designated in the virtualbox GUI on the host(it also gets auto-created but it is an editable field in the **Shared Folders** editor)... you can also get this name from `sudo VBoxControl sharedfolder list` on the guest. Mine is called **sharedsfname**.
- Adding a line (above) to /etc/fstab, designating the share **sharedsfsname**, the mount point **/files**, and the filesystem type **vboxsf**, along with some options... most importantly the **uid=1000** and the **gid=1000**. Those are the id of my user.
- After that, you should be able to mount the drive by typing `sudo mount -a`. Or by rebooting... The **auto** option ensures mounting on startup.

Virtualbox wanted you to be able to effectively do the same thing in its GUI, and for the most part you can. In the Shared Folders editor I can designate the (host's) share name and I can also give a path for the mount point of directory you wish to use as a mount point on the guest, like /home/wu-tang/data... it will mount your share if the /home/wu-tang/data exists.... or it will create /home/wu-tang/data and mount your share... On my system it gives the mount point ownership of root and the group of vboxsf (root:vboxsf). In this case you will need to add your user to the vboxsf group and have access. *(Which is why I prefer the previous mentioned method instead because you are simply giving ownership to your user without any additional alterations)*. But as soon as you exit the editor, the mount seems to happen on the guest. I could not see any options using VBoxmanage to create the share on the command line with specific permissions/ownership to avoid the extra permissions related steps.

**minor frivolous rant here...**
Another thing I just discovered that I don't like, is that it will create these folders if they don't exist, REGARDLESS of where you tell them. Be careful, the user is running the virtualbox manager and is able to create directories on the root partition of the guest. I created a second varlog directory on the guest / and it did not allow the virtualbox host to designate it as a mount point, so there 'seems' to be some safety built in there. Though the host's user would technically be trashing the user's VM, if things went wrong, so logically, it is not that alarming.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response and write up. I might be a real naive here, can you please tell me step by step instructions to follow. 1. Create an empty folder on Windows. 2. ??

Comment: 1 is create a share. 2 would be create a folder on the guest, ubuntu. I am confused again, In your very first comment you said that nothing on @N0rbert's link worked? The first answer on his link is basically what I am telling you to do. Did you really try that one? Attempt it again, you don't have to do the "VBoxManage" command(that just makes a share, you already made one). Just the following two commands. My answer does the same thing but just makes it permanent, which is why I removed it when I saw his link. Basically the answer is to not use the /media/sf_xxyyzz folders as mount points

Comment: do not create the folder/mount point as root. Do not use sudo for that... Do it the way it is provided in the aforementioned link. it is not necessary and will make it more difficult to deal with. Ensure you have full ownership and permissions on the created folder. If you need help with the share name, then look at my 3rd step in my answer.

Comment: Thank you @WU-TANG for helping me out! I was able to achieve my goal. I re-installed VirtualBox Guest Additions to give it a fresh start. And it worked. See https://imgur.com/a/J9zkGvS Now the group is showing as vboxsf instead of root